# php+MySQLでテーブルの行を追加するときに、自動生成された主キーを特定したい。

Tags: php, mysql

テーブルの行が追加されると、主キーを自動でインクリメントさせるようにしています。
行を追加したその場で、その行の主キーを取得したと思っています。

今回、複数のユーザーを管理するシステムだと仮定して、
以下のようなテーブルを作成しました。
[image: user]
以下は、主キーを特定するプログラムを自分なりにつくってみたものです。

```
<?php

// POST受け取り
$name = $_POST['name'];
$birthday = $_POST['birthday'];

// データベースサーバーに接続
$dbc = connectDb();
$dbc->query('SET NAMES utf8');

// データを追加
$stmt = $dbc->prepare("INSERT INTO user(name,birthday) VALUES(:name,:birthday);");
$stmt->bindParam(':name',$name,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':birthday',$birthday,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

// name,birthdayを使って、今回追加されたデータのcodeを特定
$stmt2 = $dbc->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE name=:name AND birthday=:birthday;");
$stmt2->bindParam(':name',$name,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt2->bindParam(':birthday',$birthday,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt2->execute();
while ($row = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  echo $row['code'];
}

// データベース切断
$dbc=null;

function connectDb() {
    try {
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=xxx;dbname=xxx';
        $user = 'xxx';
        $password = 'xxx';
        $db = new PDO($dsn,$user,$password);
        return $db;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
}
```

このプログラムを用いれば、たしかに追加した行の主キーを取得することができるのですが、
**データベースで名前、誕生日が重複していれば、複数の主キーを取得してしまうという欠点があります。** もっと簡単に、主キーを特定する方法は無いのでしょうか？
データベース詳しい方ご教示ください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql_insert_id($db)
```

でできませんか？？

Comment: 教えていただきありがとうございます。助かりました。
私の環境ではPDO::lastInsertId()というのを使えば正常に動作しました。